# Drawing Complex Semiregular Tessellations in R

Tags: r, plot, draw, tesselation

Is there a way or a package in R to draw/plot semi-regular tessellations of 2 or more regular convex geometric shapes, (i.e. hexagons+triangles) such as the ones found in the links below?

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tessellation.html

I have been trying to use center points and then various variations of voronoi algorithms but none of them have produced anything close to what I was looking for.

I'd also be interested in tessellations of more complex shapes and  demiregular tessellations if anyone knows how to do that.

Comment: These types of question are off topic. You can have a look [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/) for a list of packages by topic.

Comment: Hello Imo, I apologize. I should have written that I had already checked the CRAN repository and couldn't find any package that had a native function for this.  The solution will (I'm fairly certain) be a set of mathematical operators to draw/graph the tesselations. I should have worded my request to better reflect my hope that some one had created this code before.

Comment: Find code in any language that plots a tessellation.  With that it shpouldn't be too hard to translate into R